# Places API - com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0 Error during auto complete search "Can't load search results" some times

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using google places api in my project.But in few cases i am not finding any result and getting error 'Can't load search results.'I have download sample app from git and getting the same error.
This is a bug in google api or its just a part of setting in google api console which I forgot.

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == ON_ACTIVITY_REOPEN) {
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
                listContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mapContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fabMapListToggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.mapview_floating);
            }, 350);
            getAllProperties(mySingleton.basicSearchRequest(), false);
        }else if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
                address_txt.setText(place.getName());
                performSearch(place.getName());
            }

    }else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), status.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // The user canceled the operation.
    }
}
```